# Discord.js online members command

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I am making a discord bot and I'm trying to make a command that sends a message with all the members that are currently online.

Comment: Awesome, what's the problem?

Comment: I don't know how to do it

Comment: You're expected to attempt something before asking for help here. This is not a code writing service. If you let us know what exactly you're stuck on we can point you in the right direction

Answer (score -1):

You cannot reliably check whether a user is online or not. However you could use their `presence.status` and count all people that don't have a status of "offline". But as I said even online users are still able to set their status to "offline".

With [`cache`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMemberManager?scrollTo=cache):

```
const onlineMembers = message.guild.members.cache.filter(
  member => !member.user.bot && member.user.presence.status !== "offline"
).size;
```

With [`fetch`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=fetch):

```
const onlineMembers = (await message.guild.members.fetch()).filter(
  member => !member.user.bot && member.user.presence.status !== "offline"
).size;
```

According to the offical [Discord.js docs](https://discord.js.org/#/) these are all options a [`PresenceStatus`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/PresenceStatus) can be set to:

> The status of this presence:
>
> - online - user is online
> - idle - user is AFK
> - offline - user is offline or invisible
> - dnd - user is in Do Not Disturb

Also you may encounter some issues due to [Discord Privileged Intent](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/intents.html#privileged-intents).
You might need to explicitly allow them like so:

```
const client = new Client({
  ws: { intents: ["GUILD_PRESENCES", "GUILD_MEMBERS"] },
});
```

**Edit** as a command:

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const client = new Discord.Client();

client.on("message", async (message) => {
  if (message.author.bot) return;
  if (message.content === "!online") {
    const onlineMembers = (await message.guild.members.fetch()).filter(
      (member) => !member.user.bot && member.user.presence.status !== "offline"
    ).size;
    return message.channel.send(`Online users: ${onlineMembers}`);
  }
});

client.login("your-token");
```

Comment: how do I add it as a command such as (!online)?

Comment: Check this out: https://discordjs.guide/command-handling/ and please edit your question to show what you have done so far.

Comment: Paste my edit into your file and then please go read the SO [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).